# Retrieving data from Firebase Database using getinstance()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to extract the following data from firestore database after the user clicks the adventures tab and the data is supposed to be displayed in a list view the application works and runs but the activity appears blank. What I think is that I'm accessing the right child elements from the database, a snapshot of database is as follows, Scenario is[Firebase screenshot[r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXy3G.jpg): When the user clicks on the adventure card a list of places is displayed to the user based on the card.

```
The JSON Structure looks like this: 
{
  "Adventure" : "Adventure",
  "Beach" : {
    "Beach 1" : "Beach location 1",
    "Beach 2" : "Beach location 2",
    "Beach 3" : "Beach location 3"
  },
  "Clicked" : "Trekking",
  "Places" : {
    "Adventure" : {
      "Adventure 1" : "Adventure place 1"
    },
    "Wildlife" : "Wildlife Place 13"
  },
  "Users" : {
    "3U4nImCZZxMihPnZWV8xD19t0fa2" : "",
    
  }
}
```

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlacesList extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<FireModelH> list;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //  int i=0;

    int position;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_list);


        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String name=intent.getExtras().getString("name","Adventure");



        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycleh);

        // Intent intent=getIntent();
        //String phno=intent.getExtras().getString("phno","8777022293");

        //   Toast.makeText(this, ""+phno, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Places").child(name);


        //  progressBar=findViewById(R.id.pbar);


        recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
        recyclerView.clearOnChildAttachStateChangeListeners();
        // list.clear();
        list=new ArrayList<FireModelH>();

        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            // FireModelH fireModel=new FireModelH();

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                FireModelH value;
                list.clear();
                // Toast.makeText(history.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for(DataSnapshot x:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    // Toast.makeText(PlacesList.this, "Item: "+x.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    value=x.getValue(FireModelH.class);
                    list.add(value);
                    // Toast.makeText(PlacesList.this, "item: "+list.get(i).title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
                recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
                recyclerView.clearOnChildAttachStateChangeListeners();


                Adapterhistory adapterhistory= new Adapterhistory(list);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce=new GridLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(),1);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterhistory);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I just wanted to say that the code is working fine for another app but that database is not accessible on my end so I was trying to make my own database and connect my app to it.

Comment: Trying to isolate your problem: do you recieve the right data (value has the correct content) from Firebase? where is the problem, Firebase or recyclerView?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Avital The current problem is definitely with the firebase, because I'm not able to put the data at the right place in firebase database because of which the data is not being displayed.

Comment: @AlexMamo I'll extract and attach the JSON tree.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added the JSON Tree but as i'm new to firebase, I can't figure out what the right JSON Structure would be :(

Comment: So what exactly from the shared database would you like to display in the RecyclerView? Please also add the content of your `FireModelH` class.